# Pythonic vs Unpythonic

Tags: python, runtime

Consider these two functions that does the following: Given a word, it produces a list where every position in the word is replaced by every character in the alphabet

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
```

Version 1 (Pythonic):

```
def replace1_word( word ):
    return [word[:w]+alphabet[i]+word[w+1:] 
            for w in range(len(word)) 
            for i in range(len(alphabet))]
```

Version 2 (Unpythonic):

```
def replace1_word2( word ):
    res=[]
    for w in range(len(word)):
        for i in range(len(alphabet)):
            res.append( word[:w] + alphabet[i] + word[w+1:] )
    return res
```

I used `timeit` module to run it 1000 times and measure the timings and the average runtime difference comes down to be between `0.028` milliseconds to `0.040` milliseconds.

My questions is which part/line of the code is costly in the second version and why? They both "seem to" work the same way and return the same result in list format.

Comment: Personally, I think the second method is more Pythonic because its easier to read and understand.  Putting everything on one line makes your code hard to work with for most people.  Remember that one of Python's core principles is readability.

Comment: can you split a list comprehension into multiple lines and indent the parts like in the loops?

Comment: @iCodez I agree that it is easier to read and understand, but I have been getting used to the pythonic way of doing things. Although I have been asked my co-worker to be more pythonic as the runtime difference can be huge on bigger scale (i.e. running queue of scripts on server).

Comment: @akonsu - Yes, you can.  But he didn't here.

Comment: @iCodez: indented list comprehensions/generator expressions can be just as readable, if not more so (depending on preference and experience with Functional Programming)

Comment: @ErikAllik - Precisely.  I was making that exact point.  He should put that first method over a few lines and indent it.  Perhaps I wasn't very clear.  The first method runs better, but is terrible to read.  He should clean it up a little.

Comment: I have edited it to display list comprehension in multiple lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My questions is which part/line of the code is costly in the second
>   version and why? They both "seem to" work the same way and return the
>   same result in list format.

No they aren't. If in doubt, always profile it, it will give you a picture of the cost for each operation. Just looking at the below O/P does it now tell, what is costly in your second function?

```
>>> cProfile.run("replace1_word2('foo bar baz')")
         313 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#216>:1(replace1_word2)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
      286    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'append' of 'list' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}


>>> cProfile.run("replace1_word('foo bar baz')")
         27 function calls in 0.000 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <pyshell#220>:1(replace1_word)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 <string>:1(<module>)
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {len}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
       12    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {range}
```

> Care to explain what replaces append (or how does the version 1
>   generate the list)

In Python, function calls have extra overhead. In the former case, the `list.append` is called multiple times where as in case of list comprehension, the list gets generated as a single expression. So in a sense, there is no equivalent notation for a list comprehension with loop structures. List comprehension is a powerful tool in Python rather than a decorated syntax for loops.

**Epilogue**

If you ask me to write a function to solve this problem, I would end up something as

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> def replace1_word4(word):
         words = ('{}'.join([word[:w], word[w+1:]]) for w in range(len(word)))
         return [word.format(replace)
                 for  word, replace in product(words, ascii_lowercase)]
```

Comment: This explains a lot. Care to explain what replaces append (or how does the version 1 generate the list)?

Answer (score 2):

It probably has to do with how list comprehensions are evaluated vs for loops with `list.append` to a collector variable; if you change the second snippet to use `yield` and then wrap its result with `list()`, the performance gets closer to the first version:

```
def replace1_word3(word):
    for w in range(len(word)):
        for i in range(len(alphabet)):
            yield word[:w] + alphabet[i] + word[w+1:]
```

benchmarks:

```
In [18]: timeit replace1_word('foo bar baz ' * 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 38.7 ms per loop

In [19]: timeit replace1_word2('foo bar baz ' * 100)
10 loops, best of 3: 42.1 ms per loop

In [20]: timeit list(replace1_word3('foo bar baz ' * 100))
10 loops, best of 3: 39.7 ms per loop
```

The rest of the difference can probably be attributed to how the actualy list is constructed internally in a list comprehension vs the performance of `yield` => `generator` => `list()`.

**P.S.** Abhijit's answer can probably explain in more technical terms why `replace1_word` is faster. In any case, it looks like that `list.append` is the culprit as I guessed.

Comment: Stupid question alert: I keep seeing these In [15]: ... in people's answers. Just curious what python shell you use, seems like everyone is using it except me :)

Comment: @mlnyc: [IPython](http://ipython.org); this is why there is a `timeit` command which doesn't exist in the normal Python shell.

Comment: much appreciated, I was curious too how you get timeit working like that. I'll get hooked up and be welcomed to the 21st century ;)

Answer (score 2):

Who cares which of these ones is considered to be "pythonic" and which not? Python's primary design goal and the "pythonicness"-thing is about being easily readable, **not, as your question implies by the usage of the timeit module, about being especially performant**.

In your special case, i'd consider the second example to be more readable, but it could be made even more readable by simply iterating through the alphabet instead of iterating through its indices:

```
def replace1_word2( word ):
    res=[]
    for w in range(len(word)):
        for letter in alphabet:
            res.append( word[:w] + letter + word[w+1:] )
    return res
```

Also, you probably aren't going to need the extra creation of a list, the `yield` keyword will do okay:

```
def replace1_word2( word ):
    for w in range(len(word)):
        for letter in alphabet:
            yield word[:w] + letter + word[w+1:]
```

Lastly, while there's no official guideline to do so, many people are following the [PEP8 styleguide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). This is probably the thing that helps readability and the "pythonicness" of your code the most. In your code there are no real violations of that styleguide, except the extra whitespace in the function signature:

```
def replace1_word2( word ):  # no
def replace1_word2(word):  # yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe even better is something like this:

```
def replace1_word3( word ):
    return [word[:w]+alphabet[i]+word[w+1:] 
        for w,i in product(xrange(len(word)), xrange(len(alphabet)))]
```

But it isn't any faster than the first version, since it's effectively doing the same thing.

One slight improvement:

```
def replace1_word4( word ):
    return [word[:w]+i+word[w+1:] 
        for w,i in product(xrange(len(word)), alphabet)]
```

which is a little less wordy - for alphabet, you don't need to get the range, then deference; you can use the values directly. However, you could make the same simplification in your original code as well, and probably get the same speedup (word was 'pizzazzle':only the length matters really):

```
In [357]: %timeit replace1_word(word)
10000 loops, best of 3: 71.7 us per loop

In [358]: %timeit replace1_word2(word)
10000 loops, best of 3: 82.9 us per loop

In [359]: %timeit replace1_word3(word)
10000 loops, best of 3: 72.2 us per loop

In [360]: %timeit replace1_word4(word)
10000 loops, best of 3: 63.7 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop in `python` can be slow. The nested loop version is the slower of the two due to the extra the interpreter overhead of the for loop. 
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips

Comment: But list comprehensions are also loops (in disguise, if you will).

Comment: @ErikAllik, there are some difference. List comprehension has special `LIST_APPEND` bytecode I believe, so it should beat `make an empty list_append to it using foo loop` every time. Once you use `yield`, list comprehension offers little advantage.

Comment: Yeah, but you were talking about the nestedness of the loop, which also exists in the comprehension, not the speed advantage of the `LIST_APPEND` instruction, which is what I indirectly/unknowingly already pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think either of these is particularly Pythonic. Much better:

```
def replace1_word2( word ):
    res=[]
    for w, letter in enumerate(word):
        for alpha in alphabet:
            res.append(word[:w] + alpha + word[w+1:])
    return res
```

Comment: Better to use `yield` then and get rid of 2 more lines.